# Returning wrong file pointer

Tags: file-io, char

For some reason when I send argv it gets sends back the wrong file pointer.  For example if i send the string from argv of getty.txt it sends back shakes file pointer and if I send genesis.txt char array it sends back getty.txt.  How do I get it to send the right file pointer back?

```
for (i = 3; i < argc; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
            pattern(determineFile(argv[i]), argv[2]);
        }

FILE* determineFile(char* file) {
if (strcmp(file,"getty.txt"))
    return getty;
else if (strcmp(file, "shakes.txt"))
    return shakes;
else if (strcmp(file, "genesis.txt"))
    return genesis;
else
    return NULL;
}
```

Input:

> grep the getty.txt genesis.txt shakes.txt

Output:

> getty.txt
>
> shakes.txt: All the word's a stage,
>
> shakes.txt: And all the men and women merely players.
>
> shakes.txt: They have their exits and their entrances;
>
> genesis.txt
>
> getty.txt: Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth, upon this
>
> getty.txt: continent, a new nation, conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the
>
> shakes.txt

Comment: The code you have given does not compile. Also, please specify the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C [strcmp](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.14.html#strcmp) returns 0 if the strings match.  Try:

```
if(strcmp(a, b) == 0) {/* ... */}
```